# Convert JSON from MVC controller to array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a controller in MVC, and return JSON like below:

```
public JsonResult getData()
{
    var data = new[]{
                    new
                    {
                        x = 10,
                        y = 20,
                        name = "Jim",
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        x = 11,
                        y = 21,
                        name = "Tom",
                    }
                    };

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I have AJAX request like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:44361/home/getdata",            
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {             
        return result;
    },
    error: function (response) {
        return "faut";
    }
});
```

I want to convert the JSON result to below Array

```
var arr = [
    ['x','y','name'],
    [10,20,'Jim'],
    [11,21,'Tom']
    ];
```

Comment: can u check what you are getting in result.data ?? It should already be a java script object.

Comment: Why not just change your C# code to return the JSON in that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
const arr = [Object.keys(result[0])]
  .concat(result.map(({x, y, name}) => [x, y, name]))
```

Alternative, cross-browser solution:

```
const arr = [Object.keys(result[0])]
  .concat(result.map(function(obj) {
    return [obj.x, obj.y, obj.name]
  }))
```

Comment: I am new to js, it gives me error "Expected identifier" in '{' and '}'

Comment: @Edward Which browser are you using? It's a new JavaScript feature and it's not working in all browsers. You may need to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code. Or use the cross-browser solution I just added to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this.

```
var mainArr = [['x', 'y', 'name']];

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(result[i].x);
    arr.push(result[i].y);
    arr.push(result[i].name);

    mainArr.push(arr);
}

console.log(mainArr);
```